# API Key in path

Tags: rest, api, api-key

We have some IoT sensors that POST json payloads to an endpoint. They are configured with only a HTTPS URL to send to, no ability to setup authentication etc.

We need basic ability to see which sensor is sending data, and loosely prevent anyone from sending payloads. Full authentication will not be possible.

It was suggested we could put a token in the path and use it as a super basic API Key. I was wondering what the best format for the route should be...

/api/events/_ingest/api-key

/api/producer/api-key/events/_ingest

Comment: Have you considered a header? That should be right place for an API key.

Comment: the sensors do not currently support configuring the header they send. In later patch we will add proper auth functionality but need basic support via path for the meantime

Comment: *I was wondering what the best format for the route should be: `/api/events/_ingest/api-key` or `/api/producer/api-key/events/_ingest`*. It's a primarily opinion-based question. And my *opinion* is: both are bad because API key does not belong the URL.

Comment: I agree.  I am leaning towards /api/events/_ingest/api-key so we can eventually deprecate this approach without changing the route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering what the best format for the route should be: `/api/events/_ingest/api-key` or `/api/producer/api-key/events/_ingest`

There's no best approach here, both are **really bad.** The API key does not belong to the URL. It should be sent in the standard [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) HTTP header.

---

Once you mentioned in the comments that it will be something *temporary*, you could try a *query parameter*. It's still bad though. But you will be able to reuse this same route later, just moving the API key to a HTTP header, when your clients support it:

```
/api/events/_ingest?api-key=somecoolhashgoeshere
```

Comment: I would put it rather into the api root path: `/api/key:somecoolhashgoeshere/`, so you don't have to change the relative path (to the root) `/events/_ingest` after removing this "feature" and moving towards a standard solution. With proper coding both can have only minimal effect on the code of the service, so your solution is just as good as this one. I prefer this one only because the relative path will be a clear resource identifier.